# Saving Multiple Arrays to Text File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, save

I need to save multiple arrays to a text file with the filename the same as the variable name. I have created a vector of all the variables required using the follow lines.

```
all_var={};
vars=whos;
for(i=1:size(vars,1))
    if(~isempty(regexp(vars(i).name,'A[0-9]','match')))
        all_var{end+1}=vars(i).name;
end
end
```

I am now struggling to find a way to save all of these variable to file. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you want to save all arrays to a single text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly. Do you want to save each variable in different files? Assuming you want to save all variables in the same file with, lets say, the first value of the vector as the filename, you could try something like:

```
filename = sprintf('vector_starting_with%d.mat', vars(1).name);
save(filename)
```

In case you want separated files for each element in the vector, you could try:

```
all_var={};
vars=whos;
for(i=1:size(vars,1))
    if(~isempty(regexp(vars(i).name,'A[0-9]','match')))
        all_var{end+1}=vars(i).name;
        varsave=sprintf('vector_%d.mat', vars(i).name)
        save(varsave);
end
end
```

Sorry that it might have some bugs, right now I don't have MATLAB. Nevertheless, try to go over [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/save-structure-fields-as-separate-variables.html).

**Edit** Let me know if you try this then:

```
all_var={};
vars=whos;
for(i=1:size(vars,1))
    if(~isempty(regexp(vars(i).name,'A[0-9]','match')))
        all_var{end+1}=vars(i).name;
        filename = sprintf('%d.txt', vars(i).name);
        file = fopen(filename,'w');
        fprintf(file,vars(i).name);
        fclose(file);
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I don't think I have stated my problem very clearly. What I am trying to do is save all variables that begin with "A" to separate text files. The name of the text files needs to be the same as the variable name. Thanks